# 'reportWebVitals' is not defined

Tags: create-react-app

By [this section](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/measuring-performance), `create-react-app` said:

> By default, Create React App includes a performance relayer that
> allows you to measure and analyze the performance of your application
> using different metrics.
>
> To measure any of the supported metrics, you only need to pass a
> function into the reportWebVitals function in index.js:
>
> ```
> reportWebVitals(console.log);
> ```
>
> This function is fired when the final
> values for any of the metrics have finished calculating on the page.
> You can use it to log any of the results to the console or send to a
> particular endpoint.

However, when i add above line of code into `index.js`, i got an error:

> 'reportWebVitals' is not defined

My `index.js` source:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals(console.log);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: http://bit .ly/CRA-PWA
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that `reportWebVitals` is exist in new version of `create-react-app` (4.0.0). So in order to use `reportWebVitals`, I've create new `create-react-app` and copy `reportWebVitals.js` into my project and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Try to import the below package in your index file:

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
```

Even after importing you get the same error read the below

`reportWebVitals` is a javascript function that is introduced for measuring the performance of our app.

To avoid this issue create a new react app by using this command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

copy and paste `reportWebvitals.js` and `setupTests.js` both files into your old react project

Answer (score 0):

If you were like me and deleted the reportWebVitals file from your project because you didn't know what the point of it was, you can restore it's contents from:

- [JavaScript](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/cra-template-typescript/template/src/reportWebVitals.ts)
- [TypeScript](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/cra-template-typescript/template/src/reportWebVitals.ts)

Then, import that file into your project where you are attempting to initialize `reportWebVitals()`